# How to convert a dictionary into one condition

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a method that I need to run only once. If a long condition is satisfied. For example:

```
 if (!("a" == "a" && "b" == "b"))
    RunMethod();
```

Main problem is that I can not know in advance how many keys a dictionary can have. And before what expression may or may not be a negation symbol. In the example, the negation symbol is the value of the dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
    { "a", false },
    { "b", true }
};
```

Option with one `if` is not very suitable because the method only needs to be run once:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey("a"))
    RunMethod();
```

UPD:

```
var dictFeature = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "a", "a" },
    { "b", "a" }
};

var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
    { "a", false },
    { "b", true }
};

foreach (var i in dict)
{    
    if(dictFeature.ContainsKey(i.Key))
        RunMethod();
}
```

But if you write so then the method will be executed many times, as many keys in the dictionary.

Comment: The code snippets you provided don't make much sense. The condition in the first one always evaluates to false. You need to give a better example and state more clearly what's your goal.

Comment: So you want to build an if statement based on your dictionary values? If so what would they compare against?

Comment: Each dictionary key will check the presence of the key in another dictionary and accordingly return either true or false, and it is assumed that there can always be or not a negation operator.

Comment: Maybe add a real example. You are talking about at least 2 dictionaries and we can only see one here. What did you try? How did it go wrong?

Comment: Ok, I renewed. I added first dict.

Comment: Any reason you loop through `dict` but you don't use `i`?

Comment: I'm sorry this is a mechanical error, upd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like the following with LINQ as suggested by @V0ldek:

```
var dictFeature = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "a", "a" },
    { "b", "a" }
};

var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
    { "a", false },
    { "b", true }
};

if(dict.Any(kv => dictFeature.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
{
    RunMethod();
}
```

or more oldschool:

```
bool needsToExecute = false;

foreach (var i in dict)
{    
    if(dictFeature.ContainsKey(i.Key))
    {
        needsToExecute = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(needsToExecute)
    RunMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to run the operation if all keys in dict are present in dictFeature:

```
if(dict.Keys.All(key => dictFeature.ContainsKey(key)))
    RunMethod();
```

Comment: You want `Any`, not `All` I think.